# Problem when including a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-angles

I have the next code which makes exacty what I wanted, that is, to plot the triangle and show the values of every interior angle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (A0) at (A3);
\coordinate (A4) at (A1);
\filldraw[fill=green]
let 
    \p{11}=($(A2)-(A1)$),
    \p{12}=($(A0)-(A1)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y{11},\x{11})-atan2(\y{12},\x{12})},
    \p{21}=($(A3)-(A2)$),
    \p{22}=($(A1)-(A2)$),
    \n2={atan2(\y{21},\x{21})-atan2(\y{22},\x{22})},
    \p{31}=($(A4)-(A3)$),
    \p{32}=($(A2)-(A3)$),
    \n3={atan2(\y{31},\x{31})-atan2(\y{32},\x{32})} in
(A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle
pic[draw,
    "{$\pgfmathparse{\n1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A0--A1--A2}
pic[draw,
    "{$\pgfmathparse{\n2}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A1--A2--A3}
pic[draw,
    "{$\pgfmathparse{\n3}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A2--A3--A4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to include a foreach loop(actually two) in order to create a macro(that would be the next step), but I cannot get it. I show you the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (A4) at (A1);
\coordinate (A0) at (A3);
\filldraw[fill=green]
foreach \k in {1,2,3}
    let
    \p{\k1}=($(A\the\numexpr\x-1\relax)-(A\k)$),
    \p{\k2}=($(A\the\numexpr\x+1\relax)-(A\k)$),
    \n\k={atan2(\y{\k1},\x{\k1})-atan2(\y{\k2},\x{\k2})}, in 
(A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle
foreach \k in {1,2,3}
{pic[draw,
    "{$\pgfmathparse{\n\k}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A\the\numexpr\k-1\relax--A\k--A\the\numexpr\k+1\relax}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't know if my problem is with the syntax or with anything more complex that exceeds my skills(or maybe both). I'd appreciate any comments which help my code to be better designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the syntax of `let` which requires assignments and finds a `foreach` instead.

To get around the problem, I placed the `let` inside the `foreach` loop. And to avoid drawing and coloring the triangle 3 times, I did it only once outside the loop.

Your code giving negative angles, I modified the subtraction here:

```
\n\k={atan2(\y{\k1},\x{\k1})-atan2(\y{\k2},\x{\k2})}
```

by :

```
\n\k={atan2(\y{\k2},\x{\k2})-atan2(\y{\k1},\x{\k1})}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (A4) at (A1);
\coordinate (A0) at (A3);
\filldraw[fill=green](A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle;
\foreach \k in {1,2,3}{
\path%[fill=green]
    let
    \p{\k1}=($(A\the\numexpr\k-1)-(A\k)$),
    \p{\k2}=($(A\the\numexpr\k+1)-(A\k)$),
    \n\k={atan2(\y{\k2},\x{\k2})-atan2(\y{\k1},\x{\k1})}
     in 
% (A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle
{pic[draw,
    "{$\pgfmathparse{\n\k}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A\the\numexpr\k-1\relax--A\k--A\the\numexpr\k+1}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, apparently i completely misunderstood the question :-(

Comment: I had a lot of trouble too since I searched for 2 whole hours before understanding the problem (at least it seems to me).

Comment: Usually I haven't so much time for one question (regardless that today is Saturday :-)  )

Comment: I like to look for a problem for a long time, that's what makes me progress with TikZ and I'm still far from having understood everything. But I'm hanging in there:-).

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for. The tip for the negative angles is also very useful. My code is heading where I am intented to take it. I don't like to post this kind of codes but I've been thinking for more than two days and I was strongly desperate. Using the `let` and the `foreach` is giving me headaches.

Answer (score 4):

It is not very clear what you like to obtain (you should provide a sketch, what you like to have). See, if the following image show desired result:

[image]

With use of the `angle` library and `\pgfmathsetmacro` command the code for it is simple:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,-1);
\coordinate (A4) at (A1);
\coordinate (A0) at (A3);
\draw (A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle;
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(\i-1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(\i+1)}
\path   pic [draw,fill=red!30, radius=3mm]  
    {angle = A\j--A\i--A\k};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of using `\pgfmathsetmacro{...}{...}` you can define new counters:

```
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0, count =\k from 2] 
    in {1,2,3}
\path   pic [draw,fill=red!30, angle radius=3mm]  
    {angle = A\j--A\i--A\k};
```

**Addendum**:
Now, when desired result is more clear, the value of angles you can add on the following way (which is small variation of [AndréC answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505513/problem-when-including-a-foreach-loop/505518#505518), differences are indicated in code by % <---):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,                            % <---
                calc, 
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[       > = {Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}, % <---
/pgf/number format/precision = 1                                % <---
                    ]
\coordinate (A0) at (0,0); % <---
\coordinate (A1) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A2) at (4,-1);
\draw[fill=green!30] (A0)--(A1)--(A2)--cycle;
%
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(Mod(\i-1,3))} % <---
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(Mod(\i+1,3))} % <---
\path   let \p1=($(A\j)-(A\i)$),           % <---
            \p2=($(A\k)-(A\i)$) in         % <---
    pic [draw, <->,                        % <---
         angle radius=9mm, angle eccentricity=1.3, 
         font=\scriptsize, % <---
         "{\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan2(\y2,\x2)-atan2(\y1,\x1)} % <---
          \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\ang}}"         % <---
         ]
    {angle = A\j--A\i--A\k};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, at uploading of answer I had some unexpected problems.

Comment: I will chew on this. I got the other option yesterday and it worked for me, but this way of dealing with the counter of the loop looks easier for me.

Comment: @Aweraka, see added addendum in my answer. It may be interesting for your future similar images :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is just to mention that your approach with `foreach` inside a path, as you did, is actually the arguably cleaner version (see section **14.14 The Foreach Operation** of pgfmanual v 3.1.4) and that there is no need to define auxiliary coordinates `A0` and `A4`, which are just copies of `A3 mod3` and `A4 mod 3`, since pgf has a `mod` (and, for that matter, also `Mod`) function. So you need to define the point differences only once and reuse them. They will all have one orientation, so we need to flip one by adding `180`. To "pretty print" the angles one can again use `Mod` (where the `M` ensures that the result will be nonnegative. So everything can be condensed to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (2,5);
\coordinate (A3) at (4,-1);
\draw[fill=green] let
    \p1=($(A3)-(A1)$),
    \p2=($(A1)-(A2)$),
    \p3=($(A2)-(A3)$) in 
(A1)--(A2)--(A3)--cycle
foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \prevk using {int(1+Mod(\k+1,3))},
evaluate=\k as \nextk using {int(1+Mod(\k,3))}] in {1,2,3}
{pic[draw,   
"{$\pgfmathparse{Mod(180-atan2(\y\k,\x\k)+atan2(\y\nextk,\x\nextk),360)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$}",
    angle eccentricity=2.5]
    {angle = A\prevk--A\k--A\nextk}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]